# .net - Facebook application refresh continues

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I had create one facebook application in Asp.net 3.5 . It is working fine. But from today morning what happen application page is refresh automatically itself.

Suppose my application url is

http://apps.facebook.com/myfolder/test.aspx?
perms=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_stream&
selected_profiles=xxxxxxx

when click on this link it will redirect to 
this link
http://myliveip/xxx/xxxxx/?auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 and will go to following link.

"http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?
app_id=000000000000000000000
next=http://apps.facebook.com/test/test.aspx
display=page
locale=en_US
return_session=0
fbconnect=0
canvas=0
legacy_return=1
perms=email,user_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream
method=permissions.request"

And this process is continue in loop. Till yesterday it is working fine. I had search lot but not find any proper solution. Some post said facebook change its setting...

Note :
In my code base.RequireLogin = true is use in page_preint.
If make it as false than code is working  but Api.Session.UserId.ToString() is 0. That is not accepted. We need Api.Session.UserId.

Answer (score 0):

1)Download the latest version of the PHP-Sdk form My Apps -> your application

2)disable the option Stream post URL security in My App->your application->Edit Settings.

You might be using the old version of the PHP Sdk.